# I have a NSString like this: "Firstname Lastname". How do I convert it to "Firstname L."?

Tags: ios

I would like to change it to first name and last initial.

Thanks!

Comment: `split()` the string, take the first string and the first character `string.charAt(0)` of the second string and a period, and concatenate them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSString* nameStr = @"Firstname Lastname";
NSArray* firstLastStrings = [nameStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString* firstName = [firstLastStrings objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* lastName = [firstLastStrings objectAtIndex:1];
char lastInitialChar = [lastName characterAtIndex:0];
NSString* newNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %c.", firstName, lastInitialChar];
```

This could be much more concise, but I wanted clarity for the OP :)  Hence all the interim variables and var names.

Answer (score 4):

This would do it:

```
NSArray *components = [fullname componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSString *firstnameAndLastnameInitial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.", [components objectAtIndex:0], [[components objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:1]];
```

This assumes that fullname is an instance of NSString and contains two components separated by whitespace, so you will need to check for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code snippet, first separate string using `componentsSeparatedByString`, then join them again but only get the first character of `Lastname`

```
NSString *str = @"Firstname Lastname";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.", [arr objectAtIndex:0], [[arr objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of the parts of the name individually:

```
NSString *sourceName = ...whatever...;

NSArray *nameComponents =
    [sourceName
        componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
            [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Then, I guess:

```
NSString *compactName =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.",
        [nameComponents objectAtIndex:0],
        [[nameComponents lastObject] substringToIndex:1]];
```

That'll skip any middle names, though if there's only one name, like say 'Jeffry' then it'll output 'Jeffry J.'. If you pass in the empty string then it'll raise an exception when you attempt to get `objectAtIndex:0` since that array will be empty. So you should check `[nameComponents count]`.